# Indent error in the if statement | Discord.py

Tags: discord.py

```
    await ctx.send('Enter the channel name you want to be set as default welcome channel: ')   
else:
    await ctx.send('Only server moderators and owner can use this command')
```

the code is giving me error:
IndentationError: expected an indented block

Comment: Pleas show all the code

Comment: you would need to give us more than that block of code to understand why the error is coming

Comment: Voting to close this question as it needs details & clarity.

Comment: [Please read this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

The error isn't a DiscordError subclass.
It's only an IndentationError.
It means that your code isn't indented well.

## Example

```
>>> if (True):
    print('True')
IndentationError raised
```

You have to indent the statement block:

```
>>> if (True):
         print('True')
'True'
```

And nothing goes wrong.

## In conclusion

If your error was simply because of a wrong indentation, please fix it and accept my answer.